# Build Maven Project Without Running Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, maven-2

How do you build a Maven project without running unit tests?

Currently restructuring some code I have for a Servlet and would like to try it out in my web browser (which means running `mvn install` to get the `.war` to upload to Tomcat). I'm fully aware my UNIT tests are failing and I'm fine with that because I will fix it once I have the code the way I want. Can anyone advise?

Comment: How about NetBeans IDE?

Answer (score 490, accepted):

If you want to skip running and compiling tests:

```
mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true install
```

If you want to compile but not run tests:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

Comment: In the case of tomcat: tomcat:deploy -DskipTests

Comment: I tried `mvn install -DskipTests` and it still ran all of the tests.

Comment: Unknown lifecycle phase ".test.skip=true"

Comment: on Windows Powershell that would be mvn "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" install

Answer (score 40):

If you are using eclipse there is a "Skip Tests" checkbox on the configuration page.

> Run configurations →
>   Maven Build →
>   New →
>   Main tab →
>   Skip Tests
>   [image: Snip from eclipse]

Comment: `Goals: clean install`

Answer (score 14):

Run following command:

`mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`

Answer (score 10):

With Intellij Toggle Skip Test Mode can be used from Maven Projects tab:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
mvn clean install -Dskiptests=true
```

Now, the only difference from the answers above is that the "T" is in lower case.

Answer (score 3):

I like short version: **`mvn clean install -DskipTests`**

It's work too: `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`

If you absolutely must, you can also use the maven.test.skip property to skip compiling the tests. maven.test.skip is honored by Surefire, Failsafe and the Compiler Plugin.
`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

and you can add config in maven.xml

```
<project>
      [...]
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      [...]
    </project>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you call your classes tests Maven seems to run them automatically, at least they did for me. Rename the classes and Maven will just go through to verification without running them.